# How to derive current density from magnetic dipole moment density?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

In the case of Magneto-statics (Only time independent B field), we may solve the **B**(**r**) field from current density **j**(**r**) using ampere's law. Alternatively, we may also solve the B field if I know the magnetic dipole moment density **m**(**r**), by superpositioning the dipole fields (3rd eqn on [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_dipole)). I have a feeling that **j** and **m** are very related, they should be just different ways to describe a same thing. Is there an equation to formally illustrate this relation?

Comment: My guess: j is the curl of m. But proof?

Comment: Guessed correctly. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetization#Magnetization_current).